# return formated time as string in Go

Tags: time, go, format

I want to return the current time in a format in go, I have no trouble in format the time, but when return it as string in a func, I got stucked:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func getCurrentTime()string{
    t := time.Now().Local()
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0800"))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("current Time is:",getCurrentTime)
    t := time.Now().Local()
    fmt.Println("current Time is:", t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0800"))
}
```

The out put is :

```
current Time is: 0x400c00
current Time is: 2015-01-16 12:45:33 +0800
```

instead of

```
current Time is: 2015-01-16 12:45:33 +0800
current Time is: 2015-01-16 12:45:33 +0800
```

which I expected.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `fmt.Sprintf()`, `t.Format()` returns a `string`, just return that: `return t.Format("...")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you `main` function, you should use `getCurrentTime()` instead of `getCurrentTime`.
Like this:

`fmt.Println("current Time is:", getCurrentTime())`

When you pass a function name as the parameter, you are not calling it, the address of the function is actually printed.